# timing the execution of looped commands for discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I've put together a command that it takes a decent length of time for discord to execute:

```py
@bot.command()
async def repeat_timer(ctx, *lines):
    
    for line in lines:
        await ctx.send(line)
    
    time = "5s"
    await ctx.send(time)
```

you could send $repeat_timer 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 then it will send each numeral back as a seperate message.

I would like to know the time between the loops begining and the final iteration completing executing. i.e. in the above example the message being 10 being posted to the channel.

The above shows the code i have working so far- but i can't see how you could set the timer to know when the task was complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a ton of ways of doing this, probably the easiest and fastest is using the `time.perf_counter` function:

```py
import time
```

```py
@bot.command()
async def repeat_timer(ctx, *lines):
    start = time.perf_counter()
    for line in lines:
        await ctx.send(line)
    
    end = time.perf_counter()
    total_time = end - start # In seconds

    await ctx.send(total_time)
```

Comment: Thanks - that was really helpful! To get it to work I had to move the import time statement into the commands definition. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: No idea, any errors/tracebacks? Why can't you import it at the top of the file? It's kind of bad practice to import modules in functions

Comment: Ignoring exception in command repeat_timer:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C: \… core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C: \…MWEbot.py", line 102, in repeat_timer
    start = time.perf_counter()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'time' referenced before assignment

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\... core.py", line 859, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\...core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'time' referenced before assignment

Comment: Did you import it at the top of the file?

Comment: Yes.

Weirdly when I import time at the top of the file with the other import statements, pycharm greys it out to say its not being called, and red underlines its usage in repeat_timer.

Comment: Oh wait, you should rename the `time` variable in the command to something else, maybe python it's confused cause of that, try changing it to `total_time` or something

Comment: Ah yes, that's exactly what's happening